# Retrieve data for an autocomplete form input with angular

Tags: angularjs, forms, autocomplete

I have a form made with angular, one of the inputs is autocompleted with google maps. The problem is that if I write "Mad" and the autocomplete fills it with "Madrid" when the form is sent there is only "Mad" instead of "Madrid" and the same for longer addresses.

I had a similar problem autofilling the latitude and longitude obtained with the place of the autocomplete, but I solved it. I tried the same with the autocomplete input and is not working.

This is part of my form:

```
<fieldset class="form-group">
    <input ng-model="newCtrl.event.formatted_addres" type="text"
           ID="location-placheholder" class="form-control"
           placeholder="Where will be the event?" 
           title="Location" required />
</fieldset>
<fieldset ng-show ="false" class="form-group">
    <input ng-model="newCtrl.event.longitude" type="float" 
           ID="location-longitude" class="form-control" 
           title="Location-longitude" required />
</fieldset>
<fieldset ng-show ="false" class="form-group">
    <input ng-model="newCtrl.event.latitude" type="float" 
           ID="location-latitude" class="form-control" 
           title="Location-latitude" required />
</fieldset>
```

and this is the autocomplete function for the formatted_address field:

```
function setupAutocomplete(){
  var input = $('#location-placheholder')[0];
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function(){
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    });
    if (place.geometry.location) {
      $("#location-longitude").val(place.geometry.location.lng().toFixed(7));
      $("#location-longitude").trigger('input');
      $("#location-latitude").val(place.geometry.location.lat().toFixed(7));
      $("#location-latitude").trigger('input');
      $("location-placeholder").val(place.formatted_address);
      $("location-placeholder").trigger('input');
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      createMarker(place.geometry.location, place.formatted_address);
    } else {
      alert("The place has no location...?")
    };
  });
};
```

When I do

```
$("#location-latitude").val(place.geometry.location.lat().toFixed(7));
      $("#location-latitude").trigger('input');
```

The input of latitude fills correctly and is sent correctly, but if I do:

```
$("location-placeholder").val(place.formatted_address);
          $("location-placeholder").trigger('input');
```

It keeps sending only the part of the address that I have already written, not the rest of the address filled with the autocomplete.

Thanks

I add a fiddle with my code, I've been trying to make it work without the $http requests, but I couldn't. So I hope this is enough to evaluate my code.

http://jsfiddle.net/sjc7jtbp/1

Comment: ¿can you put a snipet with punlk,jsfiddle, etc..?

Comment: I edited the post with a fiddle

Comment: Shouldn't `<input ng-model="newCtrl.event.formatted_addres" ` be `<input ng-model="newCtrl.event.formatted_address"` ??

Comment: I had a typo at the beginning, I wrote in the database "formatted_addres" instead of "formatted_address" and when I realized it was to late to change without a rollback migration and do it again, so I changed everything to "formatted_addres". Everything works like this, except taking all the complete name of the autocomplete input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it, for some reason ajax was not targeting the input. So I created a new input hidden with ng-show="false" and I labelled it as class="autofill".

So later I aimed at it as $('.autofill') and it worked. The rest is submit this input and not the original one. Maybe it is not an elegant solution, but it works.